# Deprecated include of L.Mixin.Events (leaflet)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, leaflet

I'm having a problem with **leaflet**. I tried to insert an **ajax script** in my **index.php** in order to add a GeoJSON file from Postgis to my map. I uploaded the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXnDG.jpg) where you can see the warnng and the error that my browser shows me.

Can you please help me with that?

Below I also upload the warning:

```
    leaflet.js:5 Deprecated include of L.Mixin.Events: this property will be removed in future releases, please inherit from L.Evented instead. Error
    at y (http://localhost/webmap302/content/src/leaflet.js:5:2081)
    at Function.v.extend (http://localhost/webmap302/content/src/leaflet.js:5:14792)
    at http://localhost/webmap302/content/src/plugins/L.Control.Sidebar.js:1:31
y @ leaflet.js:5
v.extend @ leaflet.js:5
(anonymous) @ L.Control.Sidebar.js:1
leaflet.js:5 Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.
    at Wt (leaflet.js:5)
    at e.addData (leaflet.js:5)
    at e.addData (leaflet.js:5)
    at e.initialize (leaflet.js:5)
    at new e (leaflet.js:5)
    at Object.Kt (leaflet.js:5)
    at Object.success (djbasin_client.php:357)
    at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
Wt @ leaflet.js:5
addData @ leaflet.js:5
addData @ leaflet.js:5
initialize @ leaflet.js:5
e @ leaflet.js:5
Kt @ leaflet.js:5
success @ djbasin_client.php:357
u @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
k @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ djbasin_client.php:354
l @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
c @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
u @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
fire @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
u @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
_ @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
djbasin_client.php:405 {type: "FeatureCollection", features: Array(471)}
```

Comment: You're confusing a *deprecation warning* with the real problem: `Invalid GeoJSON object`. Switch from `leaflet.js` to `leaflet-src.js`, set up breakpoints, debug the value of your GeoJSON data structures.

Comment: @IvanSanchez You're right, I was wrong to write a word in the GeoJSON file.